# windows.h files have hundreds of syntax error

Tags: c, winapi, mingw, codeblocks, win32gui

When i try to make a WinApi it make a lot of errors or even crushes down. I tried the same code in CodeBlocks(it frozens) in Visual Studio(it's tha same) and also in Dev-Cpp, where i get a lot of errors.

[image]

I tried to reinstall the programs but it did not help, but when i installed codeblocks sometimes it wrote, it has some environment problems, but i could not find out what. 
I found later that the minGW file was missing but i get the same errors since.

this is the code what i try to compile and run:

```
#include <windows.h>

const char g_szClassName[] = "myWindowClass";

// Step 4: the Window Procedure
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
        case WM_CLOSE:
            DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG Msg;

    //Step 1: Registering the Window Class
    wc.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style         = 0;
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra    = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra    = 0;
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wc.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = g_szClassName;
    wc.hIconSm       = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Window Registration Failed!", "Error!",
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    // Step 2: Creating the Window
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
        g_szClassName,
        "The title of my window",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 240, 120,
        NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    if(hwnd == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Window Creation Failed!", "Error!",
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    // Step 3: The Message Loop
    while(GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);
    }
    return Msg.wParam;
}
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code, there is a problem with project settings. Try to create a new project, select "Win32 GUI project"

Comment: ps, your project is in ANSI, Visual Studio creates Unicode project by default, it will give a few errors, demanding to change `char*` to `char_t*` and `"text"` to `L"text"`

Comment: 80% errors are from 20% reason. Seem that there is a macro that defined to a valid keyword in C

Comment: it's a dump question, but how can i change "text" to L"text"?

Comment: change `const char g_szClassName[] = "myWindowClass";` to `const wchar_t g_szClassName[] = L"myWindowClass";` etc.

Comment: Please show the missing code, the macro defined before the include

Comment: Either this is not the complete code, or you are picking up the wrong header files, due to wrong build settings. In your Dev-Cpp screenshot, it looks like you are including files from `C:\Dev-Cpp\include\`. That's certainly not the standard include path for the Windows SDK. You need to fix the include paths in your IDE/project settings.